# Not authorized error when trying to create LaunchConfiguration with Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to create a config launcher for my AutoScaling group. I try to deploy it on a fresh Amazon account and I'm facing an authorization error. Not matter if I'm connected with the root account or an admin account, I always get the same error.

```
ConfigLauncher - CREATE_FAILED : You are not authorized to perform this operation.
(Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;
```

My config is :

```
  ApiScale:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref ELB
      MinSize:
        Ref: AutoScalingMinSizeParameter
      MaxSize:
        Ref: AutoScalingMaxSizeParameter
      AvailabilityZones:
        Fn::GetAZs:
          Ref: "AWS::Region"
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: ConfigLauncher
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 60
      HealthCheckType: ELB



  ConfigLauncher:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: "arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:instance-profile/ec2InstancesRole"
      ImageId:
        Ref: LinuxAmiImageIdParameter
      InstanceType:
        Ref: EC2InstanceTypeParameter
      KeyName:
        Ref: SshKeyNameParameter
      UserData: xxxxx
```

Any idea is welcome :)

Comment: The problem here is with policies your user needs to have in order to be able to launch the stack. Take a look at the IAM.

Comment: Can you detail on how you are deploying the cloudformation stack? Console, API or CLI?